# Communicating with Web through ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a basic knowledge of Web Forms but I want to design a website which communicates with web doing task such as automatically reading web pages....downloading content, recognizing tags of posts, recognizing similar content on different websites, downloading blogs articles and putting them on my website etc etc.

I also learnt the c# commands like HttpRequest, WebRequest, GetResponseStream etc etc do such task but still my knowledge lack with these.

So please suggest me some interesting techniques, c# stuff, tutorial using with i can do above mentioned task using asp.net and c# and build web communicating websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) would be a good start it is a great library for parsing html even if it's badly formatted

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is a good class to get familiar with, here's a basic tutorial:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient